# helm installation in GitLab integration responses 401

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

I want to install Helm in Gitlab's k8s integration with reference to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/#adding-an-existing-kubernetes-cluster

but responses is 401 when I clicked Helm Tiler's `Install` button.

My process is below.

1. deploy k8s in gcp
2. to get `API_URL` run this

```
$ kubectl cluster-info | grep 'Kubernetes master' | awk '/http/ {print $NF}'
https://xx.xxx.xx.xx  // set this `API_URL`
```

3. create gitlab's service account

```
$ kubectl create -f - <<EOF
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: ServiceAccount
   metadata:
     name: gitlab
     namespace: default
EOF

$ kubectl create -f - <<EOF
 kind: ClusterRoleBinding
 apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
 metadata:
   name: gitlab-cluster-admin
 subjects:
 - kind: ServiceAccount
   name: gitlab
   namespace: default
 roleRef:
   kind: ClusterRole
   name: cluster-admin
   apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
EOF

$ kubectl get secrets
default-token-xxxx   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      25d
gitlab-token-xxxx    kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      21h
tls-sample            kubernetes.io/tls                     2      24d
```

so, I choice `gitlab-token-xxxx`.

4. to get `CA Certificate` run this

```
$ kubectl get secret gitlab-token-xxxx -o jsonpath="{['data']['ca\.crt']}" | base64 --decode
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDDDCCAfSgAwIBAgIRAJ0S/Fsf1dDFRZP9TCnby60wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw
......
.....
FZ1tsRI3EbTNuKsyKtvjwg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I used this as `CA Certificate`

5. to get `Token` run this

```
$ kubectl get secret <secret name> -o jsonpath="{['data']['token']}" | base64 --decode
eyJhbGciOi.........
```

I used this as `Token`

6. I filled out in [this page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DTFw.png)

Please teach me correct way!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Which error is it, since your title says 401 and your body says 404? Also, if you have the EE version of GitLab, you will very likely have better luck asking their support for help than having us try and _guess_ what is wrong with your setup

Comment: I'm sorry. correct error is 401.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for seeing this question.

I installed it without displaying an error by the following method! Thank you very much!

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding gitlab-internal-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=gitlab-managed-apps:default
```